# Infinite loop when calling a module that uses a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In Main.tsx, I have been using useApi(opts,payload), which is a hook I made that is subscribed to changes in payload. It will make an API call whenever that variable is changed.

When I use usApi() in Main.tsx (as I have commented out), everything works fine.

It is only when I moved this logic to another functional component (Auth.tsx), and try to call it within Main.tsx that I encounter a problem. The problem is that it seems to attempt to make an API call in an infinite loop, but never throws an error.

What is happening here?

Main.tsx

```js
function Main():JSX.Element { 

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
 
  const opts = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    fail: ()=>null
  }

  const defaultPayload = {
    path: 'notes/validateAuth/',
      method: 'GET',
      body: null,
      callback: ()=>null
  }

  const [payload, setPayload] = useState<IPayload>(defaultPayload)
  //useApi(opts, payload) <---- THIS WORKS


  Auth() // <---- THIS DOES NOT

...
```

Auth.tsx

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import useApi, {IPayload} from './hooks/useApi';
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import './modal.css';
Modal.setAppElement('#root')

function Auth():JSX.Element{

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const opts = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    fail: ()=>null,
  }

  const defaultPayload = {
      path:'notes/validateAuth/',
      method: 'GET',
      body: null,
      callback: ()=>null
  }

  //const _payload = (props.payload===null)?defaultPayload:props.payload
  // console.log(_payload)
  useApi(opts, defaultPayload)

  
  return(
    <></>
  )
}

export default Auth;
```

### UseApi.tsx

In case this is needed to debug:

```js
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'
import createPersistedState from 'use-persisted-state'
import {apiUrl} from '../config'
console.log("MODE: "+apiUrl)
export interface IProps {
    username:string,
    password:string,
    fail: ()=>void
}

export interface IPayload {
    path:string,
    method:string,
    body:{}|null,
    callback: (result:any)=>any,
}

function useApi(props:IProps, payload:IPayload){

    const [accessKey, setAccessKey] = useState('')
    const useRefreshKeyState = createPersistedState('refreshKey')
    const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = useRefreshKeyState('')
    //const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = useState('')
    const [refreshKeyIsValid, setRefreshKeyIsValid] = useState<null|boolean>(null)
    // const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    // const apiUrl = '/api/'
    const [accessKeyIsValid, setAccessKeyIsValid] = useState<null|boolean>(null)

    const validHttpCodes = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204]
    
    const go = useCallback((accessKey)=>{
        const {body, method, path} = payload
        console.log('executing GO:'+accessKey)
        if(method === 'logout'){
            return logout(payload.callback)
        }
        const options = {
            method: method,
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+accessKey,
            },
            ... (body !== null) && { body: JSON.stringify(body) }
        }
        fetch(apiUrl+path,options)
        .then(response=>{
            if(!validHttpCodes.includes(response.status)){
                setAccessKeyIsValid(false)
            } else {
                setAccessKeyIsValid(true)
                response.json()
                .then(response=>{
                    payload.callback(response)
                })
            }
        })
    },[payload])

    function logout(callback:(response:null)=>void){
        setRefreshKey('')
        setAccessKey('')
        setRefreshKeyIsValid(null)
        setAccessKeyIsValid(null)
        callback(null)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(accessKeyIsValid===false){
            console.log('access key is false')
            // We tried to make a request, but our key is invalid.
            // We need to use the refresh key
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
                body: JSON.stringify( {'refresh': refreshKey} ),
            }
            fetch(apiUrl+'token/refresh/', options)
            .then(response=>{
                if(!validHttpCodes.includes(response.status)){
                    setRefreshKeyIsValid(false)
                    // this needs to trigger a login event
                } else {
                    response.json()
                    .then(response=>{
                        setRefreshKeyIsValid(true)
                        setAccessKey(response.access)
                        // setAccessKeyIsValid(true)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    },[accessKeyIsValid])


    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('responding to change in access key:'+accessKey)
        go(accessKey)
    },[accessKey,payload])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(refreshKeyIsValid===false){
            // even after trying to login, the RK is invalid
            // We must straight up log in.
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: props.username,
                    password: props.password,
                 })
            }
            fetch(apiUrl+'token/', options)
            .then(response=>{
                console.log(response.status)
                if(!validHttpCodes.includes(response.status)){
                    setAccessKeyIsValid(null)
                    setRefreshKeyIsValid(null)
                    props.fail()
                    console.log('total fail')
                }
                else { 
                    console.log('login works')
                    response.json()
                    .then(response=>{
                        setAccessKey(response.access)
                        setRefreshKey(response.refresh)
                        // setRefreshKeyIsValid(true)
                        // setAccessKeyIsValid(true) // Commenting this out disables the loop
                    })
                }
            })
        }

        
    },[refreshKeyIsValid])

};

export default useApi
```

Note: I have reasons for needing to factor this logic out, which is not evident by my abridged code.

Comment: I think I can guess what your problem is, but I really need to see the implementation of `useApi` to be sure

Comment: Thank you, I've added the source for that file.

Comment: Are you actually passing `_payload` into your hook? Or do you mean to always pass in `defaultPayload`?

Comment: I mean to pass _payload which will either be derived from props. But if props is null, then it will resort to defaultPayload. Right now I'm just leaving the default for debugging purposes.

Comment: Do you still get the problem when you pass it in from props?

Comment: Yea, it still does the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237037/discussion-between-ben-wainwright-and-raven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've spoken a little bit on chat in order to find out a little bit more about what is going on here. I'll edit your question in a moment to take out the irrelevant code so that this is easier to understand for anyone stumbling on the question.

Your original code did the following:

- Instantiated an object (`defaultProps`) within a functional component
- Passed that object in as the `default` for a `useState()` call
- Passed the state value into your hook, which was then used in the dependency array of a `useEffect()` hook

Your refactor changed it so you were directly passing the defaultProps reference into your hook *without going through a `useState()` hook* as before.

An important thing to understand about React components is that although their execution pattern is *somewhat* predictable, it is something you have no control over as a developer and so you should assume when writing your components that they may be re-rendered at any time.

Within a functional component, each re-render is a **new function execution with a new scope**. If you instantiate an object within this scope, that's a new reference variable pointing to a different area of memory each time

The problem with then using this within the dependency array of a `useEffect()` hook is that since this is a new variable on each render, it means that **each time the component is re-rendered, the useEffect hook will see a different reference, and cause the effect callback to be executed again**. This is not normally the intended behaviour.

```
const component = () => {
   
   /*
    * Each time this component
    * renders, this object is created again
    * in (probably) a different area of memory
    */
   const obj = {
      foo: 'bar'
   }

   /*
    * Although 'obj' *appears* to be the same here since it is in fact
    * a different reference, this console.log statement is going 
    * to execute every single time the component re-renders
    */
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('running effect!')
   }, [obj])

   return <div></div>
}
```

**So what is the solution?**

The original code first passed the `defaultPayload` into a `useState` call. This was the *right thing to do*. The reason for this is because component state values **do maintain the same reference in between renders** and can therefore be safely used in a `useEffect()` dependency array.

```
const component = () => {
   
   /*
    * still a different reference on each render
    */
   const obj = {
      foo: 'bar'
   }

   const [objState, setObjState] = React.useState(obj);

   /*
    * Although `obj` is a difference reference on every render
    * objState is *not*, so our `console.log` will now only execute
    * when objState changes
    */
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('running effect!')
   }, [objState])

   return <div></div>
}
```

**Alternative (but slightly pointless) Solution**

Note that you could also resolve the very specific issue experienced in this question by simply instantiating the object *outside of the functional component scope* (ie, in the module global scope). However, you will need to put it into a state variable as soon as you want to be able to change it (which the name `defaultPayload` rather suggests you will)

```
/*
 * Definitions made within the module global scope
 * are instantiated only once, when the module is imported
 */
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

const component = () => {
   
   /*
    * useEffect hook will now only ever fire once
    * since `obj` is never going to change
    */
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('running effect!')
   }, [obj])

   return <div></div>
}
```